# ComboBox: a button on every item (to delete the item from list)

Tags: delphi, combobox

I need to add a button (maybe TSpeedButton?) on every item of ComboBox. When one clicks the button the corresponding item is deleted from the list. For example:

[image]

I've seen similar discussion on SpeedButtons in string grids (here: [TStringGrid with SpeedButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514849/tstringgrid-with-speedbuttons)), but I don't know how to implement all those things on ComboBox. Could you please give me some advice or links for further reading on the topic.

Comment: Not necessary to be exactly TSpeedButton, but a button that has OnClick handler. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited the question.. Have an image to illustrate, but the Rep is too low.

Comment: Anyway, I think you'll be looking to custom draw the combo items, including a delete button, and then detect the clicks. Personally I'd be trying to find a different UI.

Comment: I mean I'd find a different way to let users delete items. Interacting with a combo drop down is pretty funky.

Comment: Oh, I see. You've given me a clue - I think that it would be more convenient to delete a selected item in ComboBox (having drop down closed).

Comment: Should I just delete the question?

Comment: No. It's a good question. Leave it here. Nothing to gain by deleting. Some of the earlier comments could be deleted though.

Comment: You can't do that with default ComboBox. The key is to pop up your own component which allows that. Have a look at TJvCheckedComboBox from JEDI JVCL. It shows own ListBox. You just want to display your own ListBox with buttons on the right side.

Comment: [subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9165643) the list, owner draw buttons, capture mouse when left button down, draw pressed look, force list to repaint, delete item when mouse up if captured, draw non-pressed look, force list to repaint, set capture to the list back. Might have problems deleting an item when the list is dropped down.

Comment: And here is one example how to draw any control. When you join the code from TJvCheckedComboBox with this, you are done  ... http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/radiolistbox.htm

Comment: Your users are going to hate this UI, IMO. It's not the same as deleting in a StringGrid where all of the rows are visible and you can see what happens when things are deleted. You're doing this in a list that will collapse and expand with things in a different order than where they appeared before. I'd seriously rethink this, and use a separate form to allow them to delete items (perhaps with a TCheckListBox, where they can check multiple items, and then a Delete button when they're ready to actually delete them).

Comment: Indeed, if you delete an item, you need to somehow refresh the drop-down list. However, the list is drawn/prepared at the moment of opening up. So upon deletion, the drop-down will have to close up anyway.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for commenting. I agree that it was not the best idea of the interaction with user. I will do the things another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the user experience comments aside, to which I agree, a solution to the question isn't really that hard.

You can do this by setting the `Style` property to `csOwnerDrawFixed`, drawing the items yourself in the `OnDrawItem` event, and deleting the selected item in the `OnSelect` event for example, as follows:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Imaging.PNGIMage;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDeleteGraphic: TPNGImage;
    FDeleteRect: TRect;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  ComboBox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  if Index >= 0 then
    ComboBox1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top, ComboBox1.Items[Index]);
  if (odSelected in State) and not (odComboBoxEdit in State) then
  begin
    FDeleteRect := Rect;
    FDeleteRect.Left := FDeleteRect.Right - FDeleteGraphic.Width;
    ComboBox1.Canvas.Draw(FDeleteRect.Left, FDeleteRect.Top, FDeleteGraphic);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
var
  MousePos: TPoint;
begin
  MousePos := ComboBox1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  MousePos.Offset(0, -ComboBox1.Height);
  if PtInRect(FDeleteRect, MousePos) then
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Delete(ComboBox1.ItemIndex);
    ComboBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDeleteGraphic := TPNGImage.Create;
  FDeleteGraphic.LoadFromFile('H:\Icons\FamFam Common\Delete.png');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDeleteGraphic.Free;
end;

end.
```

With this result:

[image: Screen shot]

You might want to (re)store the previous `ItemIndex` setting. Customize to your wishes.

Comment: Surely `OnSelect` can be fired by keyboard actions.

Comment: @David Sure. If the user choose to position the mouse cursor precisely within the delete icon, then maybe a hit on Enter might indicate a wanted deletion. Otherwise, set `FDeleteRect.Width := -1;` in the `OnKeyDown` event.

Comment: Those are not like buttons but images.

Comment: @Sertac Yeah, can OP do something too? This can be fine tuned further in many ways.

Comment: Buttons can be drawn in the same manner, and can even use the active style (if using VCL Styles).

Comment: @Jerry buttons have down, hot look, you can't do that in onselect.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, that's another story. Still much better than an image as you pointed out.

Comment: Or I should say, much closer to OP's request.

Comment: @NGLN Yes, OnSelect is just what I need. Not the buttons, but the way to solve the problem.

Comment: +1 we need more answers like these. There's a full code example, a screenshot and a working solution, so why didn't this answer have any up votes?

Comment: @Wouter It's a complicated subject matter. Usually answers that require greater expertise get fewer upvotes than answers on subjects that more people can understand and appreciate. Also, I suspect that the people that do understand the technical issues have reservations over the approach outlined.